# User Without Email?

Tags: email, user-registration

When creating a user in Wordpress an email address is required for that user. The website I'm working on requires that users remain anonymous (it's part of a research study) and I'd consider email to be an identifying piece of data. Users will be added manually, so email is not required to confirm accounts or prevent spam sign-ups.

Am I going to have to provide a fake email address for each account, or is there a way to leave this field blank?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible, just not so easily via the Users page without some hackery.

The WordPress Function wp_create_user will let you insert users without email addresses, so a little custom plugin to accept a login name and password, and a call to `wp_insert_user` or `wp_update_user` should work for you. Unfortunately I don't have time to code it up for you, but perhaps this will point you in a direction.

```
$userdata = array ('user_login' => 'someuser', 'user_pass' => 'swordfish');
$new_user_id = wp_update_user( $userdata );
```

**Update for people looking for a solution with the REST-API:**
Unfortunately, this is not possible by the rest-api. the email is required there. see: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#create-a-user

Comment: Thanks! I was creating users with wp_insert_user() and, after seeing the email column is set to refuse nulls in the database, assumed that the issue was with not providing an email address. After you pointed out that an email is not required by the WordPress API I discovered the true source of the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Using Wordpress 4.7.2, I solved this with the following hooks:

```
// This will suppress empty email errors when submitting the user form
add_action('user_profile_update_errors', 'my_user_profile_update_errors', 10, 3 );
function my_user_profile_update_errors($errors, $update, $user) {
    $errors->remove('empty_email');
}

// This will remove javascript required validation for email input
// It will also remove the '(required)' text in the label
// Works for new user, user profile and edit user forms
add_action('user_new_form', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
add_action('show_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
function my_user_new_form($form_type) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#email').closest('tr').removeClass('form-required').find('.description').remove();
        // Uncheck send new user email option by default
        <?php if (isset($form_type) && $form_type === 'add-new-user') : ?>
            jQuery('#send_user_notification').removeAttr('checked');
        <?php endif; ?>
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to WordPress' documentation, [`wp_create_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) also let's you insert users without e-mail, as it is an optional parameter. All you need to do is provide a unique username and a password.

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty old question, but is still relevant.

Anyway, @Milo definitely had the right idea.

Here is what I use and it works great. This is very convenient when you want to create users, but prefer to keep your wordpress backend on lockdown. For example if you have a blog and prefer your content authors submit their work to you, this enables you create a user for them while not actually giving them access. Or if you prefer to blog under an alias. Or it's even useful for testing purposes or I guess those "sketchy" people who want to make up a bunch of fake users for their site (you know who you are).

Add this to functions.php temporarily or use it with a useful plugin like code snippets.

```
function wpse_22754_insert_new_user() {

    $user_data = array(
    'ID' => '', // automatically created
    'user_pass' => 'swordfish',
    'user_login' => 'someuser',
    'user_nicename' => 'Some User',
    'user_email' => '',
    'display_name' => 'John',
    'nickname' => 'jsmith',
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'John',
    'user_url' => '',
    'user_registered' => '2015-06-26 10:55:55', // leave empty for auto
    'role' => get_option('default_role') // administrator, editor, subscriber, author, etc
    );

    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );

    }
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_22754_insert_new_user' );
```

If you are looking to update users from the backend after creating them, add this and you'll avoid getting the error/warning notification.

```
function wpse_22754_empty_email_error( $arg ) {
    if ( !empty( $arg->errors['empty_email'] ) ) unset( $arg->errors['empty_email'] );
}
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'wpse_22754_empty_email_error' );
```

If you'd rather use a plugin this one will do the job most likely:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-multiple-accounts/

Answer (score 0):

The "Import Users from CSV" plugin will allow you to create users with no email address. I added them with...

```
last_name,first_name,display_name,user_login
Gamble,Bill,Bill Gamble,BillGamble
```

Our club leverages the Wordpress wp_users database, but we need to have on file even those members who have no email

Answer (score 0):

I find a way on youtube , when I search "how to create users without email in wordpress" !

1. install "code snippets" plugin
2. choose "add new" in this plugin
3. choose a name for that. for example "Email not required code"

4.Enter this code:

```
// This will suppress empty email errors when submitting the user form
add_action('user profile_update_errors' , 'my_user_profile_update_errors', 10, 3);
function my_user_profile_update_errors($errors, $$update, $user){
$errors->remove('empty_email');
}

// This will remove javascript required validation for email input
// It will remove the '(required)' textin the label
// Work for new user , user profile and edit user forms
add_action('user_new_form', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
add_action('show_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
function my_user_new_form($form_type) {
?>
<script type= "text/javascript">
jQuary('#email').closest('tr').removeClass('form-required').find('.description').remove();
// Uncheck send new user email option by default
<?php if (isset($form_type) $$ $form_type === 'add-new-user') : ?>
jQuery '#send_user_notification').removeAttr('checked');
<?php endif; ?>
</script>
<?php
}
```

5. select "only run in administrayion area and choose "save changes and activate
6. now check , it works!