# Updated : how to make email optional while user registration using default wordpress form

Tags: login, user-registration, email, wp-mail, email-verification

I wonder if there is any way to make email an optional field while registering using default form. So that those who  don't know mail may leave it blank.

I got code from stackexchange but that doesn't seems to work.I added code to functions.php under theme folder.

```
add_action('user_profile_update_errors', 'my_user_profile_update_errors', 10, 3);
function my_user_profile_update_errors($errors, $update, $user) {
    $errors->remove('empty_email');
}

add_action('user_new_form', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
add_action('show_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
function my_user_new_form($form_type) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#email').closest('tr').removeClass('form-required').find('.description').remove();

    <?php if (isset($form_type) && $form_type === 'add-new-user') : ?>
        jQuery ('#send_user_notification') .removeAttr('checked');
    <?php endif; ?>
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

**UPDATE**

I mend to have optional mail registration on default registration page of wordpress (http://example.org/wp-login.php?action=register) not in dashboard.

Sorry for clarity in question .Won't repeat it again( am a newbie )

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

[Reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/user-without-email/258137#258137)

Comment: This code works well on my setup. Are you on a wordpress multisite ?

Comment: Do you have a particular error if you activate wp debug ? Do you have a cache plugin ?

Comment: @Gregory  No  brother , I am not on multisite

Comment: Look my second comment.

Comment: I'd guess that other code in WordPress assumes that the user will have an email address though. Do you really need to support users without one - are they that common?

Comment: @Rup yah bro.reason is that my site also targets those who has less knowledge  about internet. So they might not know mail. So make mail optional and username unique. Thanks buddy

Comment: @Rup  any help regarding question is very much appreciated.Thank you brother.

Comment: @Gregory Sorry ,for clarity in question.( am newbie).won't repeat it again. Please see updated question.Thanks