# Make only in user profile field email not required

Tags: plugins, php, customization

I managed to realize the possibility to create the user without the obligation of email, but when the user tries to customize the profile (edit of the website field for example), the change is not saved with the error "Error: please enter a email address. "

How can I have users save data without verifying the email field?

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are lots of questions about this on the site already with lots of good answers

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/user-without-email, there are lots of others, as well as some about specific parts such as email confirmation etc

Comment: Thanks guys, the title and my bad english deceived me :)